# spring boot - rollback on an oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am working on a spring boot app that needs to rollback all the database transactions when an error is thrown. Here for example, I am creating a file with the student and when I give it an unknown path, I have a FileNotFoundException but the save in the database is commited. I am asked to rollback the commited transactions on every technical error. Any help ?

Example of my code :

```
@Override
public boolean registerStudent(Student student){
//some code
student.setStatus("registred");
studentService.save(student);
createFile(student);
//return
}

private void createFile(Student student) throws IOException{
try {
//code to create file
} catch (IOException ex) {
//log the error
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the exception, so it's impossible to rollback.

In addition to this the registerStudent method must share the transaction with studentService.save (for example using @Transactional on both methods), otherwise studentService will save it in an isolated transaction and even if you throw the exception you won't rollback it